# Can't access members of an anonymous, nested subclass (implementing an interface)

Tags: java, class, interface, inner-classes

I have problem here. I write a piece of code like this：

```
package vh.Static;

public class Nesting {
    //static class Nested{}
    class Inner{}
    void method(){
        Inner inner = new Inner(){
            public int z =2;
            public int getZ(){
                return z;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(inner);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Nesting ne  =new Nesting();
        Inner inner = ne.new Inner(){
            public int z =1;
            public int getZ(){
                return z;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(inner);
        ne.method();
   }
}
```

I don't know how to get the var z  definding in the Inner constructor block. help me,please!
and tell me where is z local? in Inner? or Nesting

Comment: in your `method()`, return inner.getZ();

Comment: NO,it is unavailable. because ,Inner is empty class, actually have no methods and var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the *original* title of your question is really broad - you'll need to do some research:

- [Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) is contract definition only, it has no implementation
- Class can have implementation
- A [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is visible only to its containing class

But to address your specific example, in the code:

```
void method(){
    Inner inner = new Inner(){
        public int z =2;
        public int getZ(){
            return z;
        }
    };
}
```

This instantiates a new anonymous subclass of the nested class `Inner`, and then extending the anonymous subclass with a public field and a method.

The reason why the extended field + method can't be accessed is that the variable `inner` is of the base type `Inner` (to which nothing has been added - this is defined simply as `class Inner{}`), and is not of the type of the anonymous subclass. As it stands you would need to resort to nasties like reflection to access the fields + properties in the anonymous subclass, outside of the anonymous subclass itself.

```
 System.out.println(inner.getZ()); // Does not compile
```

What can be done instead is to define abstract methods on `Inner` and then override these in the anonymous class:

```
abstract class Inner{
    public abstract int getZ();
}

void method(){
    Inner inner = new Inner(){
        private int z =2; // Private fields plz, use get / setters
        public int getZ(){
            return z;
        }
    };
```

You can now access the defined `Inner` methods anywhere within the `Nesting` class

Just one note on conventions - [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) refer to the inner class (your `Inner`), as the `nested class` and the outer class (your `Nesting`) as `Outer`.

Here's the same thing defining `Inner` as an interface which is then implemented anonymously:

```
class Nesting {
    interface Inner{
        int getZ();
    }
    void method(){
        Inner inner = new Inner(){
            private int z =2;
            public int getZ(){
                return z;
            }
            private int anotherInnerMethod(){
                // Can access non-interface items as it is part of the anon subclass
                return z * z;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(inner);
        // Access getZ() through the interface
        System.out.println(inner.getZ());
    }
    // Because this method is in class Nesting, it may still access Inner
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Nesting ne = new Nesting();
        ne.method();
        Inner inner = new Inner(){
            private int z =1;
            public int getZ(){
                return z;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(inner.getZ());
        ne.method();
    }
}
```